# How to use LOB's in select statement as LOBs are not allowed in Group By Clause (TERADATA)

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some Lobs columns in my Table in Teradata DB .How to select LOB's coloumns without including it in Group By clause to avoid aggregate function error

Comment: You can't use LOBs in GROUP BY or DISTINCT. And you can't apply (windowed) aggregate functions on them. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have agregaate functions in select along with lobs , how can i create sub query to avoid group by clause

Comment: I could add a fairly generic answer to this question, but it might be better to find out exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Could you provide some sample data, your query, and what you are expecting to get as a result? With that information, perhaps there is a better approach that you could take.